# Swift 4 - How to enable / disable keyboard by using buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction

My tricky problem is :

I've 2 buttons with 2 UITextView.
Like you know, when I push an UITextView, keyboard appear. Well, this is not what I want.

I want to enable / disable the display's keyboard according a specific @IBAction taped.

The scenario is the following:
- First button (Keyboard icon) allow the user to display the keyboard to type something in one of the UITextView, with a FirstResponder init on the top one.

- Second button (REC icon) allow the user to speak and display in pre-selected TextView but **without displaying keyboard**.

I already known that there is :

> isUserInteractionEnabled

and

> textViewDidBeginEditing

But it doesn't really fit well and/or fix my issue.

Here a screen to be more explicit (don't give a mind about the third green validate button, it's just for the .POST feature) :

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean dismiss the keyboard when you click the other buttons?

Comment: Considering that one of the UITextView is selected. Yeah, this what I want definitely. I wanna to dismiss the keyboard when a specific button is pressed and make it appear when an other one is pressed.

Comment: @danyl : Please have a look at the detailed answer I posted with multiple solutions that you can try and finally one which works fine :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, You don't want the keyboard to appear when user taps on the textField but rather should come up only when user taps on Keyboard button and should dismiss on tapping other button.

All the posted answers mostly focus only on second part of showing keyboard and dismissing them on tapping button. Whats more tricky is preventing keyboard from appearing in when user taps on textField :)

**Possible solutions you can try and their cons:**

**Solution 1:**

Try setting textfield `isEnabled = false` sure this will prevent keyboard from appearing when user taps on textField but guess what Keyboard will not appear even on calling `textfield.becomeFirstResponder()` ahhh trouble :)

**Solution 2:**

implementing `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` of UITextField delegate and returing true or false based on whether used tapped on button or textField itself.

Sure it works but you will need to figure out way to tell `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` why was it triggered because of button or because of touch on textField again complications.

**My Solution:**

Use 2 textFields. One disable user interaction forever and use another textField which will never appear to user but will take care of showing keyboard when required.

Enough talk lets code :)

**Step 1:**

Lets say your textField which appears on screen is called `textField`

```
textfield.isEnabled = false
```

This will ensure whatever you do keyboard will not appear for this keyboard.

**Step 2:**

Create a temp textField of frame zero (which user can never tap :P )

```
    tempTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)
    tempTextField.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(tempTextField)
```

**Step 3:**

Now when user taps on show keyboard button, make your temp textField first responder

```
tempTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

and when user taps on other button `resignFirstResponder` for tempTextField.

```
tempTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

**Step 4:**

But wait when user types nothing appears on my textField. Wait simply implement

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == tempTextField {
        self.textfield.text = (self.textfield.text ?? "") + string
    }
    return true
}
```

**EDIT:**

You don't really need two textFields, you can achieve the same with a `UILabel` and `UITextField` as well. I chose UITextField as I am not sure what are other requirements of yours!

Problem fixed. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @danyl : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

function to dismiss KeyBoard when button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func hideKeyboard() {
     textView.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

function to get keyboard to show up:

```
 @IBAction func showKeyboard() {
     textView.becomeFirstResponder()
 }
```

Comment: He has two buttons. What you said is what I meant @rmaddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var yourTextView: UITextView

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            yourTextView.delegate = self
        }

        @IBAction func showKeyboard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.yourTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

    }

      @IBAction func hideKeyboard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.yourTextView.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> But it's not really working in my case.

Why?

You can disable the textfields interaction with (swift 3):

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Next, when you click on the keyboard button you can reenable the interaction so when the user click on one of the textfield the keyboard opens.

On the keyboard dismiss (you can see the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` callback notification) you can set the interaction to false.

Answer (score 0):

**Just copy and paste simple code for you accessory button embedded with keypad**

```
 func addKeyboardToolbar()  {
    let ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard = UIToolbar()
    ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.sizeToFit()
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "login-logo"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(doneBtnfromKeyboardClicked), for:.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 30) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
    ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard.items = [barButton]
    postTextView.inputAccessoryView = ViewForDoneButtonOnKeyboard
}


@IBAction func doneBtnfromKeyboardClicked (sender: Any) {
        self.contentView.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After 2 years, I'd find a solution already :)